# How to pass options to gatsby-plugin-typography

Tags: gatsby

Following the [official tutorial](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/part-two/), I've installed gatsby-plugin-typography, which is loading and working in the dev server.

However any options I attempt to add in `gatsby-config.js` have no effect (neither causing build errors nor any visual effect).

eg. with the following as my `gatsby-config.js` contents,

```
 module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-typography`,
      options: {
        configModule: `./src/utils/anyoldcrap.js`,
      },
    },
  ]
}
```

It doesn't matter what the 'configModule' key points to -- whether it's a non-existing file, a badly-formed .js file, or a correct .js file, it has no effect.

Is the tutorial in error here? Are the configuration mechanisms for gatsby plugins documented somewhere?

Comment: Sorry about this — we were having some trouble with our hosting provider getting the latest changes to gatsbyjs.org deployed :-(

Comment: The tutorial is updated now.

Comment: Thanks, I should have just glanced at the plugin source as did the answerer below. Not rocket science ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was racking my brain over this too. Turns out the tutorial is just outdated!

Just change `configModule` to `pathToConfigModule` and everything should be fine.

If you check out `gatsby-node.js` under the plugin folder, you'd see it was renamed.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. And thanks doubly for pointing out where the change originates.